# How to access to the bundle instance in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I just dispatched my Symfony app into a few bundles.

Some of them have a common comportement, so I want the bundle to implement an interface :

```
class KnFModMapBundle extends Bundle implements ModuleBase
```

But my question is : how can I access to the bundle instance to call implemented methods in another bundle controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/service_container.html) to make some of bundle functions to be avaliable globally. Then you will can access to service from a controller via `$this->get('service.name');`

Comment: Thanks for reply. So i have to create a service that implements my interface, and don't try to use the bundle instance.